# getProfileUserInfo is returning an empty email and an empty id

Tags: authentication

I am trying to get the email address of a Chrome user via an Extension.

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo)
{szEm=userInfo.email;}
)
if (szEm==undefined)
    return -1;
else
    return szEm;
```

This always returns a blank userInfo.email and blank id. Here is the manifest.json. I have seen other answers up here where the questioner doesn't have identity as a permission. You can see that's not true in this case.

```
  {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "key": "hhbacecbkfkibifccmofpbjhkgkjilen",
  "name": "R+D Substantiator",
  "description": "This extension logs Research activities",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistant": false
  },
 "permissions": [
 "activeTab",
 "identity",
 "identity.email",
 "https://ajax.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
 "http://localhost/*.*"
 ],
 "oauth2":{
 "client_id": "koinkhimjmddddjlmfplohggjnnmifin",

 "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
                   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]
```

}

I have also found trouble using the Developer Tool. I notice that I need to log off google and log back in prior top running a test. But besides that it is the blank email that is stopping me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've run into the same issue and filed a bug with the Chromium team: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=907425